# Обновление страницы

Tags: mobile, php, mysql

Друзья, делаю сервис голосования для телефонов!

[Пример работы](http://lxxnutsxsmu46.bitte14.in.ua/test10/index.php?org_id=%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BB%D1%8C%D1%8F%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B5)

Так вот в браузере все работает - голоса принимаются и обновляются, а вот на телефоне просто пишет "ваш голос принят", в базе обновляется, а вот не обновляет страницу с данными в самом телефоне!

Подскажите, что можно сделать!

Comment: Не знал, что голосовать можно только за и неограниченное кол-во раз.
Печаль.

Comment: Это пока в разработке - будет возможность голосовать 1 раз в сутки только за одну организацию в категории!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Друзья, оказывается мобильные телефоны не понимают META теги!
Переписал функцию обновления страницы на JS!

Comment: Я Вам скажу больше, не все телефоны понимают JS. Если у вас MVC модель, то вполне приемлемо использование header() в контроллере - http://php.net/manual/ru/function.header.php

Answer (score 0):

Не делай привязку по куки, если зайти через приватный режим браузер можно голосовать сколько хочешь, или если удалять куки!